# TestCafe - How to use both User Role and HTTP Authentication?

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, gherkin, testcafe

I am using TestCafe to automate my tests.
The problem is that i am using a CMS, and need to test two types of environments:
1. Author
2. Publish
- Eg. I want to create some content as Author, and verify the same on the Publish instance, using the same test.

The problem occurs when i want to switch between the environments because the Publish environment uses HTTP Auth. and the Author does not.

1. I wanted to use User Roles to switch between the environments. This works okay for the Author environment, but when i need to switch to Publish, i need HTTP Authentication to login. TestCafe provides this only on a test / fixture level and thus i must use a different test for the Publish instance which is not logically true and also will create more overhead for the test.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario is quite complex, so at this moment it's difficult to say precisely why you have an issue. There can be some specifics on your site or TestCafe can have some limitations. It's better to create a separate issue in the TestCafe Github repository and provide the team with a working example or url to your project. In this case we can research your project and help you with a solution.
Please use the following template to create an issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md